# IWorkspaceRoot.getFileForLocation() returns null

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to obtain IFile handler for a file in one of my projects.

I have a Java project "test" with "x.dioc" file inside. When I look in my local file system and check the file's path it's:
*C:\Users\Pawel\runtime-New_configuration\test\src\x.dioc*

Now, I try to get handler:

`IPath p = new Path("file:/C:/Users/Pawel/runtime-New_configuration/test/src/x.dioc");`
`IFile sourceFile = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(p);`

but I get `null`.

I've read that this method returns null if the file is not a part of the workspace. But when I browse "test" project in package explorer I can see "x.dioc" file there.

What might be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the file path is not correct. Why do u need to specify the complete file path when you are getting the root of the workspace programmaticaly ? You can try using any of the following strings for the file path. 

`IPath p = new Path("/test/src/x.dioc");

IFile sourceFile = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(p);`

Kindly let me know if this works.

This works:
IPath p = new Path("/test/src/x.dioc");
IFile sourceFile = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(p);
But getFileForLocation did not (at least for me).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I tried different combinations with/without device, different segments etc.

Comment: Kindly go through [this](http://eclipsesourcecode.appspot.com/jsrcs/org.eclipse.core.tests.resources/src/org/eclipse/core/tests/resources/IWorkspaceTest.java.html) link, it may be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "file:" at the beginning of your Path variable.  Simply create the path like this:

```
IPath p = new Path("C:/Users/Pawel/runtime-New_configuration/test/src/x.dioc");
```

Then your IFile sourceFile should contain the correct reference.

Answer (score 1):

I used getFile instead of getFileForLocation and it worked.   Thanks for the help! :-)

IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IFile resultFile = root.getFile(iPath);